# Error:package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist

Tags: java, android, json, intellij-idea

I have some problems with intellij.
I added Json library but when I run my program this error appear

Error:(8, 28) error: package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist

this is my code

```
package openquality.tutorialjson;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ListView listView;
   ListAdapter adapter;
   List<CubetaDTO> response;
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list,R.id.textView,response);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    class Jackson2Example {
        public void main(String[] args) {
            Jackson2Example obj = new Jackson2Example();
            obj.run();
        }
        private void run() {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                // Convert JSON string from file to Object
               /* List<CubetaDTO> response = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\staff.json"), List.class);
                System.out.println(response);*/

                // Convert JSON string to Object
                String jsonInString = "[{'TagId':123,'Estado':'Disponible'}"+
                        "{'TagId':153,'Estado':'Muerto'}"+
                        "{'TagId':324,'Estado':'Disponible'}"+
                        "{'TagId':fdger,'Estado':'Almorzando'}"+
                        "{'TagId':123423,'Estado':'Disponible'}"+
                        "{'TagId':65784,'Estado':'En el baño'}"+
                        "]";
                response = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, List.class);
            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}`
```

To add json library, y clicked in projec structure, librarias and + simbol and add the library

Here's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "openquality.tutorialjson"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
```

Comment: Show both of your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: What do I have to add?

Comment: artifact is available in maven repo so compile jar by adding into dependency.

Answer (score -1):

you need to paste .jar file into WEB-INF>lib folder and go to built path and add jar from this location and build and run project again.